# How to make thumbnails in wordpress play audio after click through stratus

Tags: image, wordpress, soundcloud, soundcloud-stratus

I probably searched through the entire web but couldn't find any help on this. Before I ask the question I must mention that I am a complete novice in web development.

I went through a lot of websites that enable you to play audio through stratus after clicking on a thumbnail. Although websites like indieshuffle.com and themusicninja do not use stratus, I was wondering how they get their photos to play songs in their audio players.

Similarly, I don't want my thumbnails to link to the post but instead I want people to play the corresponding soundcloud track after clicking on the thumbnail. Also, if it is possible to have play/pause buttons on the thumbnails it will be great.

Of course, I have ajax and stratus as well as the full width audio player installed as plugins.

I am guessing this has to do with embedding the shortcode for the track somewhere in the image.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

since you are complete new your best bet here is an album plugin or something
that will let you attach an image and have a mp3 file to relate to, and be displayed without much knowledge in coding.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Now, although I am a novice I still understand coding. I don't think there is any plugin like that. Besides, I don't want to upload mp3s. The Yahoo Webplayer is great for uploading MP3s. I want to use soundcloud URL's instead. I know a lot of websites are able to do that.

Comment: there are plugin for soundclouds too, but if you want to dive into coding then - easiest way to do this is have a custom template to display special post category that you made and just pull post thumb and content and create a fast album gallery yourself.